# How to change an image using an onclick button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, onclick

I cannot get my images to change when I click each button name. Anyone know what the issue is with my code?

It's not letting me put my code in the description.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hmwk02</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Octocats</h1>
        <img id="octocats" src= "https://octodex.github.com/images/original.png" alt="octocat" width="150"/>
       <div id="buttons"></div>

       <script>
       let names= ["Castello", "Grinchtocat", "Mummytocat", "Adventure-Cat"]; 
       let urls= ["https://octodex.github.com/images/catstello.png",
                  "https://octodex.github.com/images/grinchtocat.gif",
                  "https://octodex.github.com/images/mummytocat.gif",
                  "https://octodex.github.com/images/adventure-cat.png"];
        let lines = "";
        for(let i = 0; i< names.length; i++){
            lines += '<button onlick="showPicture(' + i +')">' + names[i] + '</button><br/>'
        }
        document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = lines;
            console.log(lines);
       </script>
       <script src="octocats.js"></script>
</body>

function showPicture(i) {
    document.getElementById("octocat").src = urls[i];
console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: place your code into the description and select it all and press 'ctr-k'

Comment: thankyou @JulianSilvestri

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine other than syntax errors, you misspelled `onclick` in your button tag and you misspelled the ID for the picture--it should be `document.getElementById("octocats")` not `document.getElementById("octocat")`

corrected code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hmwk02</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Octocats</h1>
        <img id="octocats" src= "https://octodex.github.com/images/original.png" alt="octocat" width="150"/>
       <div id="buttons"></div>

       <script>
       let names= ["Castello", "Grinchtocat", "Mummytocat", "Adventure-Cat"]; 
       let urls= ["https://octodex.github.com/images/catstello.png",
                  "https://octodex.github.com/images/grinchtocat.gif",
                  "https://octodex.github.com/images/mummytocat.gif",
                  "https://octodex.github.com/images/adventure-cat.png"];
        let lines = "";
        for(let i = 0; i< names.length; i++){
            lines += '<button onclick="showPicture(' + i +')">' + names[i] + '</button><br/>'
        }
        document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = lines;
            console.log(lines);
       </script>
       <script>
       function showPicture(i) {
          document.getElementById("octocats").src = urls[i];
        console.log(i);
}</script>
</body>
```

working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBYxgr

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the `for loop` would be to **[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** the `names` array and simply use **[createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)** method to create a new `<button>` element with a click listener for each item in your `names` array (you should avoid using inline on* handlers (onclick, oninput, etc) and use IDs and event listeners instead).

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I have described above:

```js
let names= ["Castello", "Grinchtocat", "Mummytocat", "Adventure-Cat"];
let urls= ["https://octodex.github.com/images/catstello.png", "https://octodex.github.com/images/grinchtocat.gif", "https://octodex.github.com/images/mummytocat.gif", "https://octodex.github.com/images/adventure-cat.png"];

names.map((e, i) => { // add function to each element in "names" array
  let name = document.createElement("button"); // create <button> element for each item in "names" array
  name.id = i; // assign respective index as id of each element
  name.textContent = e; // assign item string as button text content
  name.addEventListener("click", () => document.getElementById("octocats").src = urls[i]); // add click listener to each <button> that changes image src on click
  document.getElementById("buttons").appendChild(name); // append the <button> elements to your `#buttons` div.
});
```

```html
<h1>Octocats</h1>
<img id="octocats" src= "https://octodex.github.com/images/original.png" alt="octocat" width="150"/>
<div id="buttons"></div>
```